# How to make PostgreSQL use the proper query plan with this JSON

Tags: json, performance, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.3

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.4. I have a table which is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE report (id int, keyval json, time timestamp);
```

The table includes a column (`keyval`), specified as JSON. It includes many different key-value pairs, such as:

```
{"accept-language":"en-us,en;q=0.5","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate",
 "host":"192.168.1.98","accept":"text/html,application/xhtml",
 "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0",
 "connection":"keep-alive","browser":"Firefox", "OS":"Windows"}
```

Actually, the `keyval` column will contain some application-specific data, such as HTTP information shown above.

Currently, my table has over ten million records. About one fifth of the records have a `keyval` column with `"browser"` key.

I defined the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX report_browser_idx ON report (lower(keyval::json->>'browser'));
```

However, when I run the following query:

```
explain analyse select * from report 
                where lower((keyval::json->>'browser')) = 'firefox';
```

I get:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on report  (cost=1149.54..167329.46 rows=58981 width=160) (actual time=18.741..2546.882 rows=49607 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (lower((keyval ->> 'browser'::text)) = 'firefox'::text)
   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 977637
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on report_browser1_idx  (cost=0.00..1134.80 rows=58981 width=0) (actual time=17.484..17.484 rows=49607 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (lower((keyval ->> 'browser'::text)) = 'firefox'::text)
 Total runtime: 2550.518 ms
(6 rows)
```

As you can see, PostgreSQL query planner decides that it should use `Bitmap Heap Scan`, which fetches a lot of records, removes 977637, and returns 49607.

However, if I force the planner not to use Bitmap Heap Scan (using `set enable_bitmapscan = false;`), and execute the query again, I see a huge improvement:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using report_browser1_idx on report  (cost=0.44..231060.61 rows=58981 width=160) (actual time=0.091..206.649 rows=49607 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (lower((keyval ->> 'browser'::text)) = 'firefox'::text)
 Total runtime: 209.318 ms
(3 rows)
```

Notice that this time, the planner uses my index, and searches using Index Scan.
The execution time is reduced from `2550.518 ms` to merely `209.318 ms`.

I have read and understood the way Bitmap Heap Scan works from the response of [@araqnid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12261683/3910228). So, my question is **not** why PostgreSQL planner works as such. My question is:

> **How** should I define the index, and configure the planner, to respond my query using the index I defined?

Comment: Did you `analyze report`?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: Yes, I did that too. I still get the same results.

Comment: Look at the expected costs - the index scan is more expensive. Since the estimated number of rows isn't too far out, that suggests your various cost estimates might need tweaking. In particular random_page_cost - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS